# Unable to update or execute the 'expo' command in command prompt

Tags: npm, npm-install, expo

For the first time i tried to install the expo-cli on my project directory it worked. I can use `expo init` to make my first react native app in my command prompt, and run the app with `expo start`. But now when i have some new project to make with the 'expo' command like `expo init` or `expo start` or something else, it didn't work anymore. When i tried to type and enter the expo command, its always be
`'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

And now when i tried to update the expo-cli with `npm install -g expo-cli` a warning of error appeared.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-foqoNR8w
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-foqoNR8w'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-foqoNR8w'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.expo-cli-foqoNR8w'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-10T17_18_03_575Z-debug.log
```

This preventing me from doing the installation of react navigation and make a new project by using 'expo' command. And i've been search this problem on and tried to solve it but it didn't work on any various ways that i've tried. I've tried to reinstall the expo-cli but it didn't work, i've tried to use `yarn` as well but still it didn't work. I've been re-added the path for the npm and even tried to reinstall nodejs and use any various code for updating and installing the 'expo-cli' but it didn't work as expected.

Any suggest on how do i can fix this problem ?

Comment: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted`, seems like you need to run the command prompt with admin right.

Comment: I've tried it before (run as admin) but it's still an error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I delete the expo file on the path :

```
C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-foqoNR8w
```

**the file that i deleted :** expo-cli & .expo-cli-foqoNR8w

And then try to install the expo-cli again with `npm install --global expo-cli` then it work. Now i can use my `expo start` or whatever code with 'expo' in it. And also now i can install react navigation on my project directory. And i'm running the installation by using command prompt run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Run your command line as Admin and then do the following:

`npm remove -g expo-cli` to remove the existing CLI
and then `npm i -g expo-cli` to reinstall the Expo CLI.

Then you can simply login via `expo login` (if you were logged in) and take off from where you were!

Comment: When i'm trying to run the command  `npm remove -g expo-cli` i still got an error like before i asked and so does `npm i -g expo-cli`. And when i tried to run the `expo login` --> 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`